# Isomorphism and Identification between Vector Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, intuition, vector-space-isomorphism

There are many great posts on the Stack discussing intuitions of isomorphisms and some discuss isomorphisms between vector spaces. However, I have not find the answers I found very helpful in my mind, and hence this new post. Consider below:

Given $\phi:E \to (-\infty, \infty]$, we call the convex conjugate of $\phi$ to be $\phi^*: E^* \to (-\infty, \infty]$ defined as $\phi^*(f) = \sup_{x \in E} (f(x) - \phi(x))$ for all $f \in E^*$.

Note that $\phi^*(f) \geq f(x) - \phi(x)$ for all $x \in E$ and so we have $f(x) \leq \phi(x) + \phi^*(f)$ for all $x \in E$ and $f \in E^*$.

From here (this is where my confusion start), we can discuss the following example:

Let $E = \mathbb{R}$, $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{p}|x|^p$ and $\phi^*(y) = \frac{1}{p'}|y|^{p'}$ where $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p'} = 1$. Then from the inequality above, we obtain the classical Young Inequality:
$$
xy \leq \frac{|x|^p}{p} + \frac{|y|^{p'}}{p'}.
$$

My question is, what do we even mean by $\phi^*(y)$? It seems to me that $y \in \mathbb{R}$ whereas the domain of $\phi^*$ is $E^*$, making this expression no sense to me. I know this perhaps have something to do with isomorphisms? Identifying one element in a space with another element in another space while preserving space structure. However, to me what isomorphism does is that it preserves how elements act with each other in the **same** space, whereas, in some sense, here we are essentially just treating $f$ exactly as $y$, including how they act on elements of **other** spaces, which to me is not really what isomorphisms do. Can someone please explain this in detail? I have seen many times such argument, but have never made sense of it. In general, what properties of isomorphism have guaranteed us that we can do this, without thinking of the consequences? What is the rigorous way of seeing this?

**Update after Comments:**
I think I still have some remaining concerns of my question, but here is what I have understood so far from the comment:

Let $\phi: \mathbf{R} \to (-\infty, \infty]$ be a convex function such that $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{p}|x|^p$. We note that since $\mathbb{R}$ is finite dimensional, it is isomorphic to its dual, that is $\mathbb{R}^*$. **(This part I am not sure, again there are many isomorphisms between the two spaces, what makes the one mentioned in the comment special? I still have not understood from the comment.)**

Anyways, we can obtain a canonical isomorphism $J: \mathbb{R}^* \to \mathbb{R}$ through the following way:

Notice that we have
$$
\mathbb{R}^* = \{ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} | f(x) = mx, m \in \mathbb{R} \} \equiv A.
$$
To see this, let $f \in \mathbb{R}^*$, then for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $f(x) = f(1 \cdot x) = f(1) x = mx$. Thus $f \in A$. Conversely, if $f \in A$, we have $f(x) = mx$. This is a continuous linear function on $\mathbb{R}$. Hence $f \in \mathbb{R}^*$.

Great, let $J: \mathbb{R}^* \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $J(f) = m = f(1) \in \mathbb{R}$. Why is this injective? If $J(f_1) = J(f_2)$, then $f_1(1) = f_2(1)$. But $f_1, f_2 \in \mathbb{R}^*$, so by the above comment, $f_1 = f_1(1)x$ and $f_2 = f_2(1)x$. Thus $f_1 = f_2$ as $f_1(1) = f_2(1)$. Why is this surjective? Given $m \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $f \in \mathbb{R}^*$ defined as $f(x) = mx$. Indeed, this shows $J$ is an isomorphism.

Now $\phi^*: \mathbb{R}^* \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as $\phi^*(f) = \sup_x (f(x) - \phi(x))$ by definition. Now we need to make sense of $\phi^*(y)$ for $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Because of the isomorphism $J$, we can **define** safely that
$$\phi^*(y) := \phi^*(J^{-1}(y)) = \phi^*(f) = \phi^*(yx) = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} (xy - \phi(x)) = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} (xy - \frac{1}{p}|x|^p).$$
Equivalently, we are effectively constructing a new function $\tilde{\phi}^*: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\tilde{\phi}^*(y) := \phi^*(J^{-1}(y)) = \phi^*(f) = \phi^*(yx) = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} (xy - \frac{1}{p}|x|^p) \equiv: \phi^*(y).
$$

Since we have
$$
\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} (xy - \frac{|x|^p}{p}) = \frac{|y|^{p'}}{p'}
$$
where we omit the computation (cases separate into $x > 0$ and $x < 0$, then we have sub-cases for y etc.) Nice, so we have our desired result, indeed, by choosing $f(x) = yx$ for some $y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
xy = f(x) \leq \phi(x) + \phi^*(f) = \phi(x) + \phi^*(J^{-1}(y)) = \phi(x) + \phi^*(y) = \frac{|x|^p}{p} + \frac{|y|^{p'}}{p'}.
$$
This concludes the discussion.

Again, I am still confused about the isomorphism part (bolded part above). Moreover, do we **have to** go through **all** of these kind of reasoning all over again the next time when we encounter a similar situation? Are there some key steps that we can just check and safely conclude that we **can** indeed define $\phi^*(y)$ just like above in future scenarios?

**Some other words of thoughts:**

I might have realized the answer to my last question above: as long as we know the **form** of the isomorphism between two spaces, in this case, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^*$, we can simply shove whatever that the **equivalent** form of the element from the primal space into the "equation" that we have, and substitute out the original primal form of that element. This is because the same reasoning presented above applies over and over to other scenarios. Please correct me if this is not the way we should think of it.

Comment: $\mathbb R^*=\mathbb R$ with the isomorphism $(x\mapsto mx) \mapsto m$. In words: every linear map $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is multiplication by a constant.

Comment: Adding on to what @CalvinKhor's comment, perhaps you may want to write $\phi^* (x \mapsto yx) = \frac{1}{p'} |y|^{p'}$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor There are many isomorphism between the two spaces, right? What makes this one special? Why can we just choose this one? Would it not change the result if we chose the other isomorphisms between the two spaces?

Comment: Every iso is of the form $(x\mapsto yx)\mapsto yc$ for some constant $c\neq 0$. So you just end up writing lots of symbols for no benefit, e.g. $\phi^*(x\mapsto yx)=|y|^{p'}/p'$ as in Chaitanya's comment or $\phi^*(yc)=|y|^{p'}/p'$ In addition if you want an isomorphism of normed spaces then you can only choose $c=\pm1$

Comment: @CalvinKhor I just updated my question after your comment, could you please check and answer the concerns I have? Very much appreciated!

Comment: @CSquared I am in some sense redefining the function. The line following that line clarifies what I meant by "defining". Otherwise, I might not be fully understanding what your concern is.

Comment: Some isomorphisms in functional analysis are considered "canonical". For example the dualities $(L^p)^* = L^q$, $C(K)^* = M(K)$, $H^* = H$ etc. (note that the Hilbert space duality is not even linear in the complex case). If we talk about one of these canonical isomorphisms we usually omit it and identify the spaces.